# Create a list of process ordered by status

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I need create a shell script to list the process by status type.
The output must be something like:

Process running:

[process]

Process sleeping:

[process]

ETC

I did this, but doesnt work the *ps aux | awk '$8 ~ PROCESS'*:

```
for PROCESS in `ps -v | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | sort -u`; do
   echo "Procesos como $PROCESS:"
   ps aux | awk '$8 ~ PROCESS'
done
```

Cause that script outputs all the process, not filter by Process.

Any help?

Comment: first of all there is a typo, you missing $ **ps aux | awk '$8 ~ $PROCESS'**

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use `ps` and `sort`:

```
ps u | sort -rk 8
```

`-r` reverses the sort (so that the list header remains above), and `-k 8` selects the 8th field (`STAT`).

You can then select processes in a specific state using anything form `head` to `awk`, and print out whatever you like.

Comment: without **sort -rk 8** i am getting same output

Comment: By default, `ps` sorts by `PID`. You may have `ps` aliased, or it may be coincidence

Comment: uʍop ǝpısdn : Doesn´t works:
ps u | sort -rk 8 
return me just the same process each time, and they arent filter by process

Answer (score 0):

You can also use top, in non-interactive mode ( the -S option to display and sort by state):

```
top -b -n 1 -S
```

Comment: But How I pass the variable for each process? I have to use awk after. the real problem is: awk '$8 ~ PROCESS' doesnt work

Comment: The command below works pretty fine for me, it extracts the pid, the state, and the process name: `top -b -n 1 -S | awk '{print $1 "   " $8 "  " $12}'`